# Configuration.Default.ApiClient in ASP.NET MVC Core web app

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am getting started with the Docusign API and found this great example (it is much simpler than the examples on the Docusign developer site):
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-docusign-part-2-send-document-f/

The example works out of the box (downloading the zip file). I believe it is a .NET framework web app. However, when I create a new ASP.NET MVC Core web app and use the example code, I get an error at the following line:

```
Configuration.Default.ApiClient = apiClient;
```

"'Configuration' does not contain a definition for 'ApiClient' and no accessible extension method 'ApiClient' accepting a first argument of type 'Configuration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

How do I fix this? Help would be great.

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this example is more than two years old and things have changed.
If you are using the latest nuget packge of DocuSign.eSign.dll, then the code above is not going to work.
Instead you need code that looks like this:

```
    var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
    apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
```

Since it's possible you'll run into additional issues (related to auth maybe) then I would suggest you consider using the [new Quickstart from DocuSign](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart). Not only the code is downloaded for you in a ZIP just like in the link you have here, but the tool also pre-configures your personalized config file in the ZIP with the auth values that work for you.

(The code in the link you sent here is also using legacy auth that we strongly suggest you avoid. Its old and not secure and not using OAuth).

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not realize that the authentication measure has also changed. I did get the QuickStart and it works, but it was also a bit difficult to understand since the controllers are inside a rooms folder. I will revisit it again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW, there is eSignature and Rooms folders in the Quickstart, the Rooms one are for Rooms API, you can look in the eSignature folder

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering what the two folders were for. I have been trying to understand the examples step by step. How does the variable EgName in the EgController get its value?

Comment: these are internal for what we call the "Launcher" and not very pertinent to actually running DocuSign code. 
We set them in the top in a line like this:
        public override string EgName => "eg002";

Comment: Thanks so much. I see that, but I could not see how it actually gets set. I used F10 to go over the code step by step, but still could not see how it got set. I think it would be very helpful to have a simple, basic, minimal, canonical example without filters, services, configuration binding etc. Just a simple example with one action and one view, to send a document for signing.